# Fill Rectangle with Color Percentage - Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I created a box dynamically with rounded corners.

As i know width and height of the rectangle which is 300, what i am trying to achieve is to pass a variable which fills up the color as per the variable value.

So if the variable value is 10 the color should filled up untill 10ml from Top.

[image]

Here is the updated code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *myBox  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20, 300, 300)];
    myBox.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    myBox.clipsToBounds = YES;
    myBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   // [myBox addSubview:<#(UIView *)#>];
    [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 150)];
    [self.view addSubview:myBox];

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    float percentage = 0.5;
    float roundedOffPercentage = MIN(MAX(percentage, 0.0f), 1.0f);
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect), CGRectGetWidth(rect), CGRectGetHeight(rect)*roundedOffPercentage) cornerRadius:0];
    // draw the bezier path now
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass UIView and override it's - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
And do like the following. I hope it may help you.

For Example , Create One class TestView by overriding UIView Class.

TestView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TestView : UIView

@end
```

TestView.m

```
#import "TestView.h"

@implementation TestView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{

    CGRect topRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height/2.0);
    // Fill the rectangle with grey
    [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( topRect );

    CGRect bottomRect = CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height/2.0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height/2.0);
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( bottomRect );
}
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestView.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TestView *testView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 60)];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [self.view addSubview:testView];
}
```

If you're using Interface builder, make sure to change the view's class to YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW_CLASS. You can do that by selecting in the view in Interface Builder and selecting the "Identity" pane in the inspector (its the one on the far right the the "i" icon).

Comment: i tried your code by calling  [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 150)];  but it shows the same rectangle

Comment: @user580950 don't call this method manually. drawRect() will automatically called.

Comment: i commented [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 150)]; still it shows the same rectangle. I did Nslog with commenting the code, it doesn't go in - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  method

Comment: see my updated code . i have try it and it is working.

Comment: that works great Hardik, thanks for your help, i have accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UIView` and do the drawing yourself according to the percentage you need.

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
        float percentage = 0.5;
        float roundedOffPercentage = MIN(MAX(percentage, 0.0f), 1.0f);
        UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect), CGRectGetWidth(rect), CGRectGetHeight(rect)*roundedOffPercentage) cornerRadius:0];
// draw the bezier path now
}
```

Comment: i tried your code by calling  [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 150)];  but it shows the same rectangle

Comment: also i have updated question with your code, updated, which is unfortunately not working